# In PHP is there a way to test CLI interaactions?

Tags: php, phpunit

The question like in the title. The example method I have problems testing is: https://github.com/rzajac/phptools/blob/master/src/Cli/Interaction.php#L36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock the fgets() if you have namespaces in use.

```
namespace My\Namespace;

class SomeClass
{
    public static function getPassword($prompt = '')
    {
        echo $prompt;
        \system('stty -echo');

        // Notice how the global function "fgets()" is called without the leading backslash 
        // (relative instead of absolute call in a namespaced environment). 
        // This will let us later mock the call
        $pass = fgets(STDIN);

        \system('stty echo');
        return $pass;
    }
}
```

The Test file:

```
namespace My\Namespace {
    // And this here, does the trick: it will override the fgets()
    // function in your code *just for the namespace* where you are defining it.
    function fgets($Handle) {
        return 'Pa$$Word';      // Password Text for testing
    }

include_once './SomeClass.php';

class Test_SomeClass extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * This will test the success case.
     * @test
     */
    public function testPass()
    {
        $dummy = new \My\Namespace\SomeClass;
        $this->assertEqual('Pa$$Word', $dummy->getPassword());
    }
}
```

[This Post](https://marcelog.github.io/articles/php_mock_global_functions_for_unit_tests_with_phpunit.html) discusses a socket example as well that handles exceptions.